# Working with jQuery Metadata - can't read HTML5 data attributes

Tags: jquery, html, metadata

I'm trying to use HTML5 data- attributes and read them with the jQuery plugin.

First of all, does the DOCTYPE matter in this case? (I'm not worried about validation)

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<ul id="quiz">
  <li data-career="math" class="first">
    <span>Question 1</span>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" />
    <input type="radio" name="question1" />
    <input type="radio" name="question1" />
  </li>
  <li data-career="science">
    <span>Question 2</span>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" />
    <input type="radio" name="question2" />
    <input type="radio" name="question2" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then **THIS** throws an error `(a is undefined)`

```
$.metadata.setType("html5");
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = $("#quiz .first").metadata();
    console.log(data);
});
```

**Also** `console.log(data.career)` **doesn't work either.**

***I'm using jQuery 1.4.2.***

*P.S. Is metadata now included as part of jQuery?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of 1.4.3 HTML 5 [data attribute](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/16/jquery-143-released/) were supported.

From the release notes:

> For example, given the following HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'></div>
```

> All of the following jQuery code will
>   work.

```
$("div").data("role") === "page";
$("div").data("hidden") === true;
$("div").data("options").name === "John";
```

Comment: Yeah I believe it works in IE4+, any specific ones you're after?

Answer (score 3):

You're using 0.0.1 of a version too old:

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data-
>   attributes will be automatically
>   pulled in to jQuery's data object.

Usage:

```
$('#quiz .first').data('career');
```

As for the metadata plugin, I don't believe the `html5` type option exists - [see API](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Metadata/jQuery.metadata.setType#typename). I believe you want:

```
$.metadata.setType('attr', 'data-career');
```

Comment: 0.0.1 of a version too old. What are the odds +1

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't able to the use the latest jQuery version (for whatever reason) you can still access the attributes with the `.attr()` method.

```
var data = $("#quiz .first").attr('data-career');
```